# How to resolve ORA-04042 and ORA-00942 errors when granting privileges?

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration, privileges, sql-grant

I am trying to grant EXECUTE and READ privilege to a user.

When I grant execute I get:

```
grant EXECUTE on SYS.KIR_DOKUMENT to ktest2

Error report -
ORA-04042: procedure, function, package, or package body does not exist
04042. 00000 -  "procedure, function, package, or package body does not exist"
```

When I grant read I get:

```
grant READ on SYS.KIR_DOKUMENT to ktest2

Error report -
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:
```

But I checked the status of the table in `dba_objects` and they are valid.

Query

```
select owner, object_name, object_type from dba_objects where object_name
```

gives this output:

[image: dba_objects query output]

The same grants have to given to another user in my database:

[image: dba_object_privs output for another object]

How can I resolve these errors?

Comment: The second error could be a privilege issue - which user are you running those commands as? Or it could be a type, owner or name mismatch; please edit your question to include the output from `select owner, object_name, object_type from dba_objects where object_name = 'KIR_DOKUMENT'`. Are you really creating objects in the SYS schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your question edit, the object is a directory; so you have to include the `DIRECTORY` keyword:

```
grant READ, EXECUTE on DIRECTORY KIR_DOKUMENT to ktest2;
```

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/GRANT.html) says (emphasis added):

> The *on_object_clause* identifies the object on which the privileges are granted. Users, **directory objects**, editions, data mining models, Java source and resource schema objects, and SQL translation profiles **are identified separately** because they reside in separate namespaces.)

and

> **ON DIRECTORY**
>
> Specify the name of the directory object on which privileges are to be granted. You cannot qualify *directory_name* with a schema name.

and also [gives an example](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/GRANT.html#GUID-20B4E2C0-A7F8-4BC8-A5E8-BE61BDC41AC3).